# How do I make a function that resets a while loop?

Tags: c++

I have made a program that outputs `0 3 6 9 12`. Now, I want to make a function called `reset()` that resets the program, so it outputs the same numbers after 12. How do I do that?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void byThrees();
void reset(); 

int i = 0; 

int main()
{
    byThrees();   
    return 0; 
}

void byThrees()
{
    while(i<13) {
        cout << i << ' '; 
        i += 3; 
    }  
}

void reset()
{
     
    
}
```

Comment: Passing the starting value to the function would suffice. And it would eliminate a global variable.

Comment: `i = 0;` may come in handy at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use global variables when you can avoid it! And right now, you can avoid it.

No one else wants to use `i` except `byThrees()`. And it sounds like you don't want the value of `i` to persist across runs of `byThrees()`. So just make it a local variable in the function:

```
void byThrees()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i<13) {
        cout << i << ' '; 
        i += 3; 
    }  
}
```

Now whenever you want to print your `0, 3, 6, 9, ...` series, just call `byThrees()`:

```
int main() {
    byThrees();
    std::cout << std::endl; // Add a newline between runs
    byThrees();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Now, I want to make a function called reset() that resets the program, so it outputs the same numbers after 12" pretty sure OP means that they want to output the next sequence of 5 number by threes on the second call

Answer (score 0):

Another method to do it, if you want to save memory and just keep one global variable (at least I think this saves memory) is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int i = 0; 

int main()
{
    run(); // this function both resets i to 0 and runs byThrees()
    return 0; 
}

void byThrees()
{
    while(i < 13) {
        cout << i << ' '; 
        i += 3; 
    }  
}

void run()
{
    i = 0;
    byThrees();
}
```

Basically, whenever you run the function `run()`, your code will reset the global variable i to 0 and run `byThrees()` with i being 0 initially. This means that you can repeatedly call `run()` in your code and every time it will output `0 3 6 9 12`.

If what you mean in your post is that you want your code to output `0 3 6 9 12` and then `15 18 21 24 27` on the next call (and so on), you could do something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int i = 0, nextI = 0; // nextI is a variable that stores the next starting position of i 

int main()
{
    run(); // will output "0 3 6 9 12"
    run(); // will output "15 18 21 24 27"
    run(); // will output "30 33 36 39 42"
    return 0; 
}

void byThrees()
{
    while(i < nextI + 13) {
        cout << i << ' '; 
        i += 3; 
    }
    nextI += 15; // increases nextI for the next time "run()" is called
}

void run()
{
    i = nextI;
    byThrees();
}
```

This code basically keeps track of where the list of numbers left off and continues from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was just what i needed:-)